# CSS Inheritance: Overriding a parent selector that is a descendant selector

Tags: css, inheritance, css-selectors

How can I make this link use the child selector without changing or removing the parent selector?  (I want the link to be blue.)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .parent a { color:Red; }
            .child { color:Blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <a class="child" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
                stackoverflow
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is surprising to me that the parent overrides the child in this case!

Comment: The parent overrides the child because ".parent a" is more specific than ".child". As Obalix indicated, you need to make your child selector more specific, and a.child will do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `a.child` as the selector.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .parent a { color:Red; }
            a.child { color:Blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <a class="child" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
                stackoverflow
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is due to CSS specificity. The extra `a` after `.parent` makes it more specific than just `.parent`, and correspondingly, more specific than just `.child`. Obalix's suggestion gives the selectors the same specificity, with both having a base HTML element and a class designation. When specificity is equal, it will then apply the deepest value specified in the hierarchy, as you were expecting.

This article (and the resources to which it links) do a great job explaining CSS specificity: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Answer (score 4):

For future exploring http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

basically you can count selectors value in this order

```
Inline | ID | Class/pseudoclass | Element
1      | 1  | 1                 | 1
```

where Inline = 1000, ID = 100, Class = 10, Element = 1

In your case 
  `.parent a == 11` and `.child == 10` thats why parent overrides child element style.